# One of my drop down menus, the "Create Content" option under the parent "Content" tab has dissapeared. How can I recover it? (I'm using Drupal 7)

Tags: 7

One of my drop down menus, the "Create Content" option under the parent "Content Management" tab has dissapeared. The missing "Create Content" would normally be under "Content Management."

How can I recover it? (I'm using Drupal 7).

Help much appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using admin menu, right? A blog post about [rebuilding the drupal admin menu](http://andreys.info/blog/2013-02-10/rebuild-drupal-7-juggled-administration-menu) says you can:

- Delete you current links via SQL `DELETE FROM menu_links WHERE menu_name='management'`.
- Clear all caches at Administration > Configuration > Development (or just: http://example.com/admin/config/development/performance if your menu is ruined at this point). Drush users can of curse use drush cc all or even drush cc menu

Disclaimer, I didn't try it myself. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! **I was able to figure it out!**

I clicked:

- site building
- menus
- list menus
- navigation [www.yourwebsite.com/
  admin/build/menu-customize/navigation]
- create content
  [www.yourwebsite.com/node/add]

I can go in and create content, even though it's not listed in my Drupal admin panel. Next step is to figure out how to move it back to it's proper place in the admin panel. But at least I can create content now.